# Filter out all keys in a recursive serialized zeep dict if not required in subsequent SOAP request

Tags: python-3.x, zeep

I am building a [`zeep`](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/index.html)-based Python SOAP client.

In my data model design, I store the the serialized response dictionary using zeep's `serialize_object` helper function for a `get` method call.  I intend to allow for data model manipluation of the python object for various keys in the data model dict, and then be able to use the data model as an argument for a subsequent `update` SOAP call.

The problem is that the returned values in the `get` response do not match the WSDL's `update` definition.  I therefore want to "diff" the two dicts recursively, and delete any keys that do not meet the requirement in the `add` definition.

However, I'm uncertain how to extract a recursive dict representation of a zeep object using the object factory `Client.get_type()`.

My wsdl contains this, as per zeep's wsdl dump:

`ns0:AddPhoneReq(phone: ns0:XPhone, sequence: xsd:unsignedLong)`

`XPhone` is:

`ns0:XPhone(name: ns0:UniqueString128, description: ns0:String128, product: , class: , protocol: , protocolSide: , callingSearchSpaceName: ns0:XFkType, devicePoolName: ns0:XFkType, commonDeviceConfigName: ns0:XFkType, commonPhoneConfigName: ns0:XFkType, networkLocation: , locationName: ns0:XFkType, mediaResourceListName: ns0:XFkType, networkHoldMohAudioSourceId: , userHoldMohAudioSourceId: , automatedAlternateRoutingCssName: ns0:XFkType, aarNeighborhoodName: ns0:XFkType, loadInformation: ns0:XLoadInformation, vendorConfig: ns0:XVendorConfig, versionStamp: ns0:String128, traceFlag: ns0:boolean, mlppDomainId: ns0:String128, mlppIndicationStatus: , preemption: , useTrustedRelayPoint: , retryVideoCallAsAudio: ns0:boolean, securityProfileName: ns0:XFkType, sipProfileName: ns0:XFkType, cgpnTransformationCssName: ns0:XFkType, useDevicePoolCgpnTransformCss: ns0:boolean, geoLocationName: ns0:XFkType, geoLocationFilterName: ns0:XFkType, sendGeoLocation: ns0:boolean, lines: {({line: ns0:XPhoneLine[]} | {lineIdentifier: ns0:XNumplanIdentifier[]})}, phoneTemplateName: ns0:XFkType, speeddials: {speeddial: ns0:XSpeeddial[]}, busyLampFields: {busyLampField: ns0:XBusyLampField[]}, primaryPhoneName: ns0:XFkType, ringSettingIdleBlfAudibleAlert: , ringSettingBusyBlfAudibleAlert: , blfDirectedCallParks: {blfDirectedCallPark: ns0:XBLFDirectedCallPark[]}, addOnModules: {addOnModule: ns0:XAddOnModule[]}, userLocale: , networkLocale: , idleTimeout: , authenticationUrl: xsd:string, directoryUrl: xsd:string, idleUrl: xsd:string, informationUrl: xsd:string, messagesUrl: xsd:string, proxyServerUrl: xsd:string, servicesUrl: xsd:string, services: {service: ns0:XSubscribedService[]}, softkeyTemplateName: ns0:XFkType, defaultProfileName: ns0:XFkType, enableExtensionMobility: ns0:boolean, singleButtonBarge: , joinAcrossLines: , builtInBridgeStatus: , callInfoPrivacyStatus: , hlogStatus: , ownerUserName: ns0:XFkType, ignorePresentationIndicators: ns0:boolean, packetCaptureMode: , packetCaptureDuration: , subscribeCallingSearchSpaceName: ns0:XFkType, rerouteCallingSearchSpaceName: ns0:XFkType, allowCtiControlFlag: ns0:boolean, presenceGroupName: ns0:XFkType, unattendedPort: ns0:boolean, requireDtmfReception: ns0:boolean, rfc2833Disabled: ns0:boolean, certificateOperation: , authenticationMode: , keySize: , keyOrder: , ecKeySize: , authenticationString: ns0:String128, upgradeFinishTime: xsd:string, deviceMobilityMode: , remoteDevice: ns0:boolean, dndOption: , dndRingSetting: , dndStatus: ns0:boolean, isActive: ns0:boolean, isDualMode: ns0:boolean, mobilityUserIdName: ns0:XFkType, phoneSuite: , phoneServiceDisplay: , isProtected: ns0:boolean, mtpRequired: ns0:boolean, mtpPreferedCodec: , dialRulesName: ns0:XFkType, sshUserId: ns0:String50, sshPwd: ns0:String255, digestUser: ns0:String255, outboundCallRollover: , hotlineDevice: ns0:boolean, secureInformationUrl: ns0:String255, secureDirectoryUrl: ns0:String255, secureMessageUrl: ns0:String255, secureServicesUrl: ns0:String255, secureAuthenticationUrl: ns0:String255, secureIdleUrl: ns0:String255, alwaysUsePrimeLine: , alwaysUsePrimeLineForVoiceMessage: , featureControlPolicy: ns0:XFkType, deviceTrustMode: , earlyOfferSupportForVoiceCall: ns0:boolean, requireThirdPartyRegistration: ns0:boolean, blockIncomingCallsWhenRoaming: ns0:boolean, homeNetworkId: xsd:string, AllowPresentationSharingUsingBfcp: ns0:boolean, confidentialAccess: {confidentialAccessMode: , confidentialAccessLevel: }, requireOffPremiseLocation: ns0:boolean, allowiXApplicableMedia: ns0:boolean, cgpnIngressDN: ns0:XFkType, useDevicePoolCgpnIngressDN: ns0:boolean, msisdn: ns0:String128, enableCallRoutingToRdWhenNoneIsActive: ns0:boolean, wifiHotspotProfile: ns0:XFkType, wirelessLanProfileGroup: ns0:XFkType, elinGroup: ns0:XFkType, ctiid: xsd:positiveInteger)`

I can do this as such:

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.helpers import serialize_object

client = zeep.Client(**client_kwargs)  # client_kwargs just has connection and wsdl info, not shown here...
zeep_obj = client.get_type("ns0:XPhone")
print((serialize_object(zeep_obj)))
```

However, this doesn't return a `dict`.

Can anyone suggest a way to filter dict to only include return the necessary key/values required for a specified SOAP call using zeep?  Is there a better approach that makes use of the zeep library in a more efficient way to interact with the objects that it generates from the wsdl?

Comment: Have you been able to find any solutions?

Comment: I solved it myself using a recursive inspection of the data model.  I will probably post the solution soon.

Comment: Sweet, I was having a similar issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

get_type return a constructor.
I have:

```
xtype = self.__client__.get_type('ns0:XPhone')()
```

regards.